# R: HAC by NeweyWest using dynlm

Tags: r, time-series, regression

This is what I would like to do:

```
library("lmtest")
library("dynlm")
test$Date = as.Date(test$Date, format = "%d.%m.%Y")
zooX = zoo(test[, -1], order.by = test$Date)
f <- d(Euribor3) ~ d(Ois3) + d(CDS) + d(Vstoxx) + d(log(omo)) + d(L(Euribor3))
m1 <- dynlm(f, data = zooX, start = as.Date("2005-01-05"),end = as.Date("2005-01-24"))
m2 <- dynlm(f, data = zooX, start = as.Date("2005-01-25"), end=as.Date("2005-02-14"))
summary(m1)
summary(m2)
coeftest(m1, vcov=NeweyWest)
coeftest(m2, vcov=NeweyWest)
```

There is no problem with the function `summary(m1)`
However if I want to use HAC by NeweyWest i.e.`coeftest(m1, vcov=NeweyWest)`
I get the following error message and I do not know why: `Error in na.fail.default(as.ts(x)) : missing values in object`
What do I have to change on my code in order to get the result using `coeftest()`? Note: there are no missing values as you can see from the sample data. Many thanks!

Sample Data:

```
    Date    Euribor3    Ois3    Vstoxx  CDS omo
1   03.01.2005  2.154   2.089   14.47   17.938  344999
2   04.01.2005  2.151   2.084   14.51   17.886  344999
3   05.01.2005  2.151   2.087   14.42   17.950  333998
4   06.01.2005  2.150   2.085   13.80   17.950  333998
5   07.01.2005  2.146   2.086   13.57   17.913  333998
6   10.01.2005  2.146   2.087   12.92   17.958  333998
7   11.01.2005  2.146   2.089   13.68   17.962  333998
8   12.01.2005  2.145   2.085   14.05   17.886  339999
9   13.01.2005  2.144   2.084   13.64   17.568  339999
10  14.01.2005  2.144   2.085   13.57   17.471  339999
11  17.01.2005  2.143   2.085   13.20   17.365  339999
12  18.01.2005  2.144   2.085   13.17   17.214  347999
13  19.01.2005  2.143   2.086   13.63   17.143  354499
14  20.01.2005  2.144   2.087   14.17   17.125  354499
15  21.01.2005  2.143   2.087   13.96   17.193  354499
16  24.01.2005  2.143   2.086   14.11   17.283  354499
17  25.01.2005  2.144   2.086   13.63   17.083  354499
18  26.01.2005  2.143   2.086   13.32   17.348  347999
19  27.01.2005  2.144   2.085   12.46   17.295  352998
20  28.01.2005  2.144   2.084   12.81   17.219  352998
21  31.01.2005  2.142   2.084   12.72   17.143  352998
22  01.02.2005  2.142   2.083   12.36   17.125  352998
23  02.02.2005  2.141   2.083   12.25   17.000  357499
24  03.02.2005  2.144   2.088   12.38   16.808  357499
25  04.02.2005  2.142   2.084   11.60   16.817  357499
26  07.02.2005  2.142   2.084   11.99   16.798  359999
27  08.02.2005  2.141   2.083   11.92   16.804  355500
28  09.02.2005  2.142   2.080   12.19   16.589  355500
29  10.02.2005  2.140   2.080   12.04   16.500  355500
30  11.02.2005  2.140   2.078   11.99   16.429  355500
31  14.02.2005  2.139   2.078   12.52   16.042  355500
```

**Edit**I think the problem is in this command: `zooX = zoo(test[, -1], order.by = test$Date)`, namely the function `order.by()`. If you delete this part, all else equal you can compute HAC by NeweyWest.( Of course you also need to change `start = as.Date("2005-01-25")`to the index number, e.g`start=50`.) But by deleting it you lose the start and end Date in the regression output, which was very useful. So if anyone knows a way around it, please let me know!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NeweyWest` calculates the 'lag' with this code:

```
lag <- floor(bwNeweyWest(x, order.by = order.by, prewhite = prewhite, 
        ar.method = ar.method, data = data))
```

... and when called with the default arguments it replicates your (and my replication of it)  error:

```
>bwNeweyWest(m2,lag = NULL, order.by = NULL, prewhite = TRUE, adjust = FALSE, 
+     diagnostics = FALSE, sandwich = TRUE, ar.method = "ols", 
+     data = list(), verbose = FALSE)
Error in na.fail.default(as.ts(x)) : missing values in object
```

The example on the `?NeweyWest` page suggests that pre-specifying a lag was the original strategy. I've run your `coeftest` calls with lags of 2,3, and 4 and do not see much sensitivity to the choice of lags:

```
coeftest(m1, vcov=NeweyWest(m1, lag = 2, prewhite = FALSE) )
#-------------
t test of coefficients:

                  Estimate  Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)   
(Intercept)    -0.00088591  0.00024838 -3.5667 0.007329 **
d(Ois3)        -0.01256761  0.20243315 -0.0621 0.952020   
d(CDS)          0.00010732  0.00097169  0.1104 0.914774   
d(Vstoxx)       0.00121163  0.00051398  2.3573 0.046150 * 
d(log(omo))     0.01245017  0.01916762  0.6495 0.534190   
d(L(Euribor3)) -0.42173541  0.11765274 -3.5846 0.007141 **
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

#----------
coeftest(m2, vcov=NeweyWest(m2 , lag = 2, prewhite = FALSE ) )
#------------
t test of coefficients:

                  Estimate  Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)  
(Intercept)    -0.00055562  0.00029246 -1.8998  0.08992 .
d(Ois3)         0.25659641  0.17004507  1.5090  0.16558  
d(CDS)         -0.00276703  0.00197776 -1.3991  0.19530  
d(Vstoxx)      -0.00091397  0.00063662 -1.4357  0.18493  
d(log(omo))    -0.01524269  0.02810579 -0.5423  0.60076  
d(L(Euribor3)) -0.51430803  0.17335182 -2.9668  0.01578 *
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

I'm not sure whether this is an oversight on the part of the `dynlm` authors or the `sandwich` authors. You might send them an email to get more authoritative comment on statistical validity matters.

Comment: Many thanks! Unforetunately I am new to R. But I just tried the following:But I just tried the following:`coeftest(m1, vcov=NeweyWest(m1, prewhite = FALSE), order.by=test$Date )`. Now there isnt a error message anymore. But I am not sure if tha what I did is correct. What do you think?

Comment: What I'm reading in this material online suggests that you need to assess the nature of the autocovariance estimates in order to decide whether omitting prewhitening will introduce significant bias: www.wouterdenhaan.com/papers/HAND30.pdf

Comment: I've fixed the problem for the development version of the `sandwich` package now. It will be part of the next CRAN release. In this case, however, applying Newey-West standard errors is not feasible anyway. Either one should use a model that does not accout for autocorrelation and then try to adjust for it with HAC standard errors - or one should use a dynamic model and then get the autoregressive part of the model right. But estimating a mis-specified dynamic model where HAC standard errors are necessary does not work.