# R: compute waldtest using dynlm

Tags: r, time-series

I ran the following two regressions:

```
library("dynlm")
library("lmtest")
zoop <- (test1[, -1])
f <- d(y) ~ d(x)+ d(z) + d(m) + d(log(p))
m1 <- dynlm(f, data = zoop, start = 1,end = 15)
coeftest(m1, vcov=NeweyWest)
m2 <- dynlm(f, data = zoop, start = 16,end = 31)
coeftest(m2, vcov=NeweyWest)
```

which gives me the output for m1:

```
               Estimate  Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)  
(Intercept) -0.00068055  0.00021691 -3.1374  0.01056 *
d(x)         0.27475798  0.10605395  2.5907  0.02692 *
d(z)         0.00046720  0.00129363  0.3612  0.72550  
d(m)         0.00047590  0.00024276  1.9604  0.07838 .
d(log(p))    0.01876845  0.00829852  2.2617  0.04723 *
```

and the output for m2:

```
               Estimate  Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)  
(Intercept) -0.00037592  0.00023431 -1.6044  0.14309  
d(x)         0.29475934  0.12946162  2.2768  0.04882 *
d(z)        -0.00514108  0.00219475 -2.3424  0.04384 *
d(m)        -0.00011535  0.00065369 -0.1765  0.86383  
d(log(p))   -0.00501189  0.03535847 -0.1417  0.89040
```

I would like to calculate the waldtest for parameterequality for example for the variables d(z) from both models i.e: d(z) -d(z) = 0 (where the first d(z) is from the modell m1 and the second d(z) is from m2. How can this be done using R? And a second similar question: I also would like to compute the waldtest for example for model one e.g. d(z)-d(x) = 0? Many thanks in advance!

Data Sample:

```
Date         y       x      m       z       p
03.01.2005  2.154   2.089   14.47   17.938  344999
04.01.2005  2.151   2.084   14.51   17.886  344999
05.01.2005  2.151   2.087   14.42   17.95   333998
06.01.2005  2.15    2.085   13.8    17.95   333998
07.01.2005  2.146   2.086   13.57   17.913  333998
10.01.2005  2.146   2.087   12.92   17.958  333998
11.01.2005  2.146   2.089   13.68   17.962  333998
12.01.2005  2.145   2.085   14.05   17.886  339999
13.01.2005  2.144   2.084   13.64   17.568  339999
14.01.2005  2.144   2.085   13.57   17.471  339999
17.01.2005  2.143   2.085   13.2    17.365  339999
18.01.2005  2.144   2.085   13.17   17.214  347999
19.01.2005  2.143   2.086   13.63   17.143  354499
20.01.2005  2.144   2.087   14.17   17.125  354499
21.01.2005  2.143   2.087   13.96   17.193  354499
24.01.2005  2.143   2.086   14.11   17.283  354499
25.01.2005  2.144   2.086   13.63   17.083  354499
26.01.2005  2.143   2.086   13.32   17.348  347999
27.01.2005  2.144   2.085   12.46   17.295  352998
28.01.2005  2.144   2.084   12.81   17.219  352998
31.01.2005  2.142   2.084   12.72   17.143  352998
01.02.2005  2.142   2.083   12.36   17.125  352998
02.02.2005  2.141   2.083   12.25   17  357499
03.02.2005  2.144   2.088   12.38   16.808  357499
04.02.2005  2.142   2.084   11.6    16.817  357499
07.02.2005  2.142   2.084   11.99   16.798  359999
08.02.2005  2.141   2.083   11.92   16.804  355500
09.02.2005  2.142   2.08    12.19   16.589  355500
10.02.2005  2.14    2.08    12.04   16.5    355500
11.02.2005  2.14    2.078   11.99   16.429  355500
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest approach is to fit a nested model with interactions rather than two separate models. So you can first generate a factor that encodes the two segments:

```
fac <- factor(as.numeric(time(zoop) > as.Date("2005-01-24")))
fac <- zoo(fac, time(zoop))
```

And then you can fit a model where all coefficients are constrained to be equal (`M0`) and one where they differ (`M1`). The latter is equivalent to the separate models `m1` and `m2` that you fit above:

```
M0 <- dynlm(d(y) ~ d(x)+ d(z) + d(m) + d(log(p)),
  data = zoop, start = as.Date("2005-01-04"))
M1 <- dynlm(d(y) ~ fac * (d(x)+ d(z) + d(m) + d(log(p))),
  data = zoop, start = as.Date("2005-01-04"))
```

Then you can easily test all coefficients individually for differences by looking at

```
coeftest(M1, vcov = NeweyWest)
## t test of coefficients:
## 
##                   Estimate  Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)   
## (Intercept)    -0.00068055  0.00020683 -3.2904 0.003847 **
## fac1            0.00030463  0.00027961  1.0895 0.289561   
## d(x)            0.27475798  0.09503821  2.8910 0.009361 **
## d(z)            0.00046720  0.00129029  0.3621 0.721280   
## d(m)            0.00047590  0.00028483  1.6708 0.111147   
## d(log(p))       0.01876845  0.01134940  1.6537 0.114617   
## fac1:d(x)       0.02000136  0.16417829  0.1218 0.904315   
## fac1:d(z)      -0.00560828  0.00237869 -2.3577 0.029261 * 
## fac1:d(m)      -0.00059126  0.00073696 -0.8023 0.432305   
## fac1:d(log(p)) -0.02378034  0.03454593 -0.6884 0.499540   
## ---
## Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
```

The line of `fac1:d(z)` has the test for the difference in `d(z)` slopes. And if you want to test all coefficients jointly, you can do:

```
waldtest(M0, M1, vcov = NeweyWest)
## Wald test
## 
## Model 1: d(y) ~ d(x) + d(z) + d(m) + d(log(p))
## Model 2: d(y) ~ fac * (d(x) + d(z) + d(m) + d(log(p)))
##   Res.Df Df      F  Pr(>F)  
## 1     24                    
## 2     19  5 3.7079 0.01644 *
## ---
## Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
```

For complete reproducibility, I include the code that I have used to read the data:

```
zoop <- read.zoo(textConnection("Date         y       x      m       z       p
03.01.2005  2.154   2.089   14.47   17.938  344999
04.01.2005  2.151   2.084   14.51   17.886  344999
05.01.2005  2.151   2.087   14.42   17.95   333998
06.01.2005  2.15    2.085   13.8    17.95   333998
07.01.2005  2.146   2.086   13.57   17.913  333998
10.01.2005  2.146   2.087   12.92   17.958  333998
11.01.2005  2.146   2.089   13.68   17.962  333998
12.01.2005  2.145   2.085   14.05   17.886  339999
13.01.2005  2.144   2.084   13.64   17.568  339999
14.01.2005  2.144   2.085   13.57   17.471  339999
17.01.2005  2.143   2.085   13.2    17.365  339999
18.01.2005  2.144   2.085   13.17   17.214  347999
19.01.2005  2.143   2.086   13.63   17.143  354499
20.01.2005  2.144   2.087   14.17   17.125  354499
21.01.2005  2.143   2.087   13.96   17.193  354499
24.01.2005  2.143   2.086   14.11   17.283  354499
25.01.2005  2.144   2.086   13.63   17.083  354499
26.01.2005  2.143   2.086   13.32   17.348  347999
27.01.2005  2.144   2.085   12.46   17.295  352998
28.01.2005  2.144   2.084   12.81   17.219  352998
31.01.2005  2.142   2.084   12.72   17.143  352998
01.02.2005  2.142   2.083   12.36   17.125  352998
02.02.2005  2.141   2.083   12.25   17  357499
03.02.2005  2.144   2.088   12.38   16.808  357499
04.02.2005  2.142   2.084   11.6    16.817  357499
07.02.2005  2.142   2.084   11.99   16.798  359999
08.02.2005  2.141   2.083   11.92   16.804  355500
09.02.2005  2.142   2.08    12.19   16.589  355500
10.02.2005  2.14    2.08    12.04   16.5    355500
11.02.2005  2.14    2.078   11.99   16.429  355500"),
format = "%d.%m.%Y", header = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thanks! I used this code since I have my CSV on my desktop. `zoog <- read.zoo("C:/Users/USER/Desktop/test1.csv", sep=";", format = "%d.%m.%Y", header = TRUE)
fac <- factor(as.numeric(time(zoog) > as.Date("2005-01-24")))
fac <- zoo(fac, time(zoog))
M0 <- dynlm(d(y) ~ d(x)+ d(z) + d(m) + d(log(p)),data = zoog, start = as.Date("2005-01-04"))
M1 <- dynlm(d(y) ~ fac * (d(x)+ d(z) + d(m) + d(log(p))),data = zoog, start = as.Date("2005-01-04"))
coeftest(M1, vcov=NeweyWest)`. somehow I get an error message: `Error in na.fail.default(as.ts(x)) : missing values in object`. with summary it works.But why?

Comment: and is it not possible to compute a  waldtest (for d(z)-d(z)=0) using my two models I posted in the original question? Because I fitted several models and would have to change them all.

Comment: Of course, it is _in principle_ possible to compute all necessary information from separate fitted models. However, there is no straightforward R function that does this (as far as I know). So refitting should be simpler. If you have many such fitted models, then just conducting multiple Wald tests is likely to lead to liberal results and false interpretations. In that case, a formal structural change test should be employed rather than several Wald tests. With the `strucchange` package it is possible to do so, see `?M1Germany` in the `dynlm` package for a worked example.

Comment: As for the error with the Newey-West standard errors, this is still the same as: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30003047/r-hac-by-neweywest-using-dynlm#comment48192634_30004672 (I've used the fixed devel-version of `sandwich` in my example.)

Comment: oh ok, your answer is very helpful. But  could you please specify what you mean by: I've used the fixed devel-version of sandwich in my example. and provide the code to do so? Many thanks

Comment: I didn't provide the patch but it's essentially just dropping the time index before computing the bandwidth as pointed out in the other thread.

Answer (score 1):

Question 2:

```
m3<- update(m1, formula = . ~ . - d(x))
waldtest(m1,m3)
```

As per the comment of Achim Zeileis, this should be:

```
linearHypothesis(m1, "d(z) = d(x)")
```

Comment: This will just test whether the coefficient of `d(x)` in the current time period is significantly different from zero - not whether the coefficients of `d(x)` and `d(z)` are the same. The Wald test for the latter can be carried out with `linearHypothesis()` from the `car` package: `linearHypothesis(m1, "d(z) = d(x)")`